# Imported database very slow on a simple query

Tags: mysql, query-performance, mysql-5.6, amazon-rds

A production database has been exported to a separate location for various reasons, however the dumped/imported database is performing much slower on some very specific queries. Here is 2 queries on production:

```
mysql> SELECT count(id) FROM payments;
+-----------+
| count(id) |
+-----------+
|    964390 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.14 sec)

mysql> SELECT count(id) FROM payments WHERE is_held = True;
+-----------+
| count(id) |
+-----------+
|         0 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.32 sec)
```

meanwhile the imported database:

```
mysql> SELECT count(id) FROM payments;
+-----------+
| count(id) |
+-----------+
|    963770 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.20 sec)

mysql> SELECT count(id) FROM payments WHERE is_held = True;
+-----------+
| count(id) |
+-----------+
|         0 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (37.20 sec)
```

So when including a non-indexed boolean in the WHERE-clause, the performance of the imported database drops by over 100 times.

An explain for the queries shows the same result in both databases:

```
mysql> explain SELECT count(id) FROM payments WHERE is_held = True;
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | payments | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 739335 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I've tried an `OPTIMIZE payments;` run on the imported database, it didn't help, though the output was:

```
mysql> OPTIMIZE TABLE payments;
+----------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table    | Op       | Msg_type | Msg_text                                                          |
+----------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| payments | optimize | note     | Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead |
| payments | optimize | status   | OK                                                                |
+----------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (2 min 13.01 sec)
```

The database is hosted in Amazon RDS, so my access to slow query logs and looking at hardware etc is a bit limited.

Being on RDS, I've tried upsizing the instance type a couple times, which I believe will move the database to new hardware, and in each case there's been no significant improvement.

I've run this query many times over the last few days, but now when I run it twice in a row it finishes instantly, and I can start a new MySQL connection and it is instant from the first run. I can even scroll up my terminal window and observe multiple earlier runs where it was slow, though in each case delineated by an RDS instance resize.

The reason I investigated this in the first place is a scheduled task hits this every 30 seconds and the scheduled tasks were starting to overlap and consume all my workers from other tasks so it was definitely recurring regularly before, not just first run.

I've re-enabled the scheduled task again, and it seems that the first run was slow, 33 seconds, but the second run was 2 seconds.

Comment: The theory is that it has to read data from disk into memory first time.

Comment: I've re-enabled the scheduled task again now, and it seems that the first run was slow, 33 seconds, but the second run was 2 seconds. The only different now I think is that the RDS spec was possibly a bit low before, however decent single user performance in all other areas (as far as I know) of the application in this non-production import lead me to think hardware spec was not an issue. Anyway, thanks for the direction!

Comment: If you figure out a solution, please answer your question and accept it. You won't get any credits for accepting your own question, but it can be upvoted by others (I will).

Comment: Thanks. I'll downsize now to see if I can replicate the issue, perhaps the RDS resize was increased beyond a threshold that made caching of this query or the related data possible.

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the principles.

- (I assume `id` is the primary key of the table and the table is InnoDB.)
- `SELECT count(id) FROM payments;` will read the entire table.  Or it may read some secondary index, which necessarily includes the PK.
- The first time you touch a table, the data is sitting on disk must be read into RAM for processing.  Since it needs to read the entire table, that could take some time.
- If you run another query on the same table, it can skip the I/O.  This is often a factor of 10 faster.
- If the first query used a secondary index, but the `WHERE is_held = True` needs was not involved in that index, then this query will need to read the entire *data* BTree.  One of your tables apparently had it cached already (0.32s) and the other did not (37s).
- Don't use `COUNT(id)` unless you need to avoid counting any rows with `id IS NULL`, which cannot happen.  Instead, use simply `COUNT(*)`.
- `INDEX(hash_id, id)` would make some of your queries run faster because they could run entirely in that index's BTree.
- Upgrading/downgrading the server is unlikely to change performance -- unless the table is bigger than the buffer_pool.  In this case, the table cannot be cached to make the *second* query fast.

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABL`, `SHOW TABLE STATUS`, and the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.